# Reverting from Internet Explorer 9 to 8

Tags: internet-explorer-9

I'm using Internet Explorer 9 on Windows 7 (x86). The only reason I upgraded from IE8 was because various JavaScripts were not working properly. They work fine in IE9, but I don't like this version at all. If I revert to IE8, will this also set back the JavaScript implementation, or was that a separate Windows update?

Comment: Have you tried Uninstalling it

Comment: No, I haven't tried uninstalling IE9, because if it brings back the script errors from IE8 I'll have to go through the whole process of upgrading again.

Comment: You should update to IE 10 or 11 ASAP. IE9 is old and slow. It also don't support many new web standards

Comment: Well, I don't find IE9 slow, but I dislike the way MS has been continuously removing or hiding features from the browser while adding new annoyances. It has also gotten harder to customize the interface to my liking, so I won't be installing a newer version any time soon.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't actually need Internet Explorer - say for a web-application or other business need - then Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, and Opera make excellent alternatives.  And the up-side is that not only will they be faster but they will also render more pages correctly than Internet Explorer does.

Comment: I also have Firefox, although I've been staying with version 15.0.1 instead of upgrading it. It does outperform IE, has a better UI and is far more flexible with regard to configuration, but some of the sites I use are rendered much more accurately in IE. Also, I'm using scripts in a text editor for looking up selected text on various websites, like Google Translate and Wikipedia. If I use Firefox, it enters the parameters incorrectly, which causes error messages from the sites. IE enters the parameters perfectly every time.

Comment: I use Google Chrome, it has served me perfectly.  However, if your needs dictate IE then that is what it is.

Comment: I think I need to put my original question another way: When IE8 was replaced by IE9, did the resulting improvement in JavaScript support come from the new browser version alone, or from one or more Windows libraries that got updated along with the browser? If the latter was the case, would I lose the updates of those libraries on reverting to IE8?

Comment: I believe each version of IE is a complete bundle.  You downgrade the browser you downgrade javascript.

Comment: Yes, you're probably right. Looks like I'll be using Firefox more and more, because I've been liking IE less and less. I think I must have used the first version of IE, which I ran on Windows 3.1 back in 1997; it didn't even come close to what Netscape could do at that time.